# redirect pipe's read end to a file descriptor

Tags: c, pipe, io-redirection, dup2

I have two child processes they share their parent's common pipe descriptors. There is no problem for closing ends etc. The problem is I wish to redirect pipe's read end to a file descriptor instead of holding a buffer and writing the buffer's content to a file. Is it possible? My code snippet as follow

```
// we're sure we can read from fd[0], I did it sucessfully
// I mean there is no problem about the communication

int open_fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
if (dup2(open_fd,fd[0]) == -1) {
    perror("error ");
    return 1;
}
if (close(open_fd) == -1) {
    perror("close error");
    return 1;
}
```

When I did the above code, I doesn't write into the file called as `filename`. By the way, is there a need to close open_fd by calling `close(open_fd)`? Since `dup2` closes it already.

Comment: Typically, you would do `dup2(a,b); close(a)`.  Doing `dup2(a,b); close(b)` doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thanks sir, I edited it. So, what is the problem now? What should I do?

Comment: You cannot magically change a pipe into a file by duplicating file descriptors.

Comment: @IanAbbott so should I do that hold a buffer, read into buffer, open file for writing and write into the file, respectively?? Or what should I do?

Comment: @concurrencyboy It depends. Why do you need to create a pipe in the first place?

Comment: @IanAbbott I need it, I cannot change its structure now. for syncronizely implementation pipe (|).

Answer (score 1):

You've probably misunderstood the purpose of `dup2`. It just changes "the meaning" of the file descriptor, so that it now "points" to the same stream as the other descriptor. But it doesn't in any way transfer data from one file descriptor to another. To actually achieve what you want you can try [splice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html):

```
int open_fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);
splice(fd[0], NULL, open_fd, NULL, size, 0);
```

Note that you'll have to specify how much data you want to transfer (`size` variable in above example).

Comment: Neat use of `splice` although it is Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

> When I did the above code, I doesn't write into the file called as `filename`.

Of course not.  When you call `dup2(open_fd,fd[0])`, you make the integer value stored in `fd[0]` refer to the same file that `open_fd` does, but that has to has nothing directly to do with what happens to bytes fed into the write end of the pipe.  It affects them only indirectly, by causing the file descriptor number whose value was initially stored in `fd[0]` to first be closed if it is open.

A file descriptor is basically a key to a table mapping integers to open file descriptions in the kernel.  `dup2()` changes what open file description the target FD is mapped to; it does not modify the open file description itself or affect its semantics, and it's at *that* level where the pipe lives.

Bytes written to the write end of a pipe are obtained from the read end of the pipe by reading it.  However you do that, they initially reside in memory and / or in CPU registers.  To make them go from there to a file, you need to *send* them there.  For example, you might set up a thread whose purpose is to read whatever bytes are available from the pipe, and then writes them to your file.